# (Python) Capitalize first letter of every word without using .title() or .capitalize()

Tags: string, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to find a way to capitalize the first letter of each word in a given phrase, excluding a few words (such as and, the, is) and it needs to be inputed by the user. Basically, I want to make a .title() program without using .title() or .capitalize(). Recreating .title() in a sense.

Example:

```
s = #split, join, upper, lower, etc. functions here 

s = input('Enter a sentence: ')

>>>Enter a sentence: the world and me
The World and Me
```

Edit: I have searched over multiple posts, none of which were able to answer the specific question I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem down to its most basic components.  First, you will want some way to capitalize a word.  You say in your question that you can't use .title() / .capitalize(), etc... so I will assume .upper() is out as well.

So you want a function like this

```
def capitalize_word(word):
    # do something to ensure word starts with a capital letter
    # and modify it if it doesn't
    return word
```

And you are going to want a function that takes a sentence, breaks it into words, and capitalizes each of them (ignoring your exclusion words for now)

```
def titlecase_sentence(sentence):
    # break the sentence on spaces
    words = sentence.split()
    capitalized_words = []
    # iterate through your words and store the capitalized version of each
    for word in words:
        capitalized_word = capitalize_word(word)
        capitalized_words.append(capitalized_word)
    # join your capitalized words back into a sentence 
    capitalized_sentence = " ".join(capitalized_words)
    return capitalized_sentence
```

So the two things to figure out are: 1. How does `capitalize_word` work, and 2. How do we deal with your exclusion words.

The first one is pretty straight forward if you use the `ord` built-in function.  `ord` returns the ordinal value of an ascii character (its numeric value).  The ordinal of `'a'` is 97, the ordinal of `'z'` is 122.  Upper case letters come earlier in the numeric values and are `'A'` at 65 and `'Z'` at 90.  So you can check whether the ord of the first character of word is between 65 and 90, if it isn't then you know you have a lowercase letter.  Converting between a lowercase and capital letter is as easy as subtracting 32 from the ordinal and changing it back into an ascii character via the `chr` built-in.  Using this you end up with something like

```
ord_Z = ord('Z')
ord_A = ord('A')

def capitalize_word(word):
    first_ord = ord(word[0])
    if not (ord_A <= first_ord <= ord_Z):
        word = chr(first_ord - 32) + word[1:]
    return word
```

Now we just need to handle your special words that do not get capitalized except when beginning a sentence.

I will leave that part as an exercise, but you essentially want to ALWAYS run the first word the `capitalize_word` function, and conditionally run the remaining words through it.  If the current word in the iteration is one of your special words then you simply add the word without calling `capitalize_word`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to split the string into words is `words = s.split(' ')` (although regular expressions is usually better).

Then you can iterate over the words and capitalize them if they're not whitelisted, and then rejoin them into a string:

```
words = s.split(' ')
whitelist = {'and', 'the', 'is'}
capitalized = ' '.join([word.title() if word not in whitelist else word for word in words])
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, you should explain why. It helps everyone, especially me.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I assume it is because you used `title()` which the OP says cannot be used.  Also, if a string started with a whitelist word, it would not be capitalized.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't catch that it was completely without using `.title()`. In this case, yes @sberry your answer explains the solution very well.